# Is the anime Junketsu no Maria depicting Christian god as a brutal and merciless god?

Tags: junketsu-no-maria

It seems that in the anime, the God only brought sorrow but not peace to people, and showed no mercy to those on earth.

Is Junketsu no Maria anti-Christian or something? Is it trying to depict Christian god as a brutal god?

Comment: In my opinion, the author involving the religion is only a means to an end of conveying the message: People should learn to stand on their own instead of waiting for the help of others.

Comment: From an "in-topic" point of view, I think this question is opinion driven. Going completely off topic, I don't see how a story where the christian god brings sorrow and general nuisances is that far away from what is told about him.